# self.__dict__.update(Solver.DEFAULTS, **config) How to provide custom arguments?

Tags: python, dictionary, pytorch, arguments

I am referring to the code form this repo- https://github.com/thuml/Anomaly-Transformer/blob/main/solver.py

In line no. 70, what is `__dict__.update`?

```
class Solver(object):
    DEFAULTS = {}

    def __init__(self, config):

        self.__dict__.update(Solver.DEFAULTS, **config)
```

`config` are the arguments for the file obtained form a shell script executed, but what if I am running the code in a jupyter notebook and want to provide the `config` separately in a new cell of code, how would I do so?

I have created a dictionary as shown below

```
config = {"lr": 1e-4, "num_epochs": 2, "win_size":20,"input_c":6, "output_c":6,"batch_size":8,"anormly_ratio":4.00}
```

I am trying to get this function to run by passing teh dictionary I created to main function `main(config)`-

```
def main(config):
    solver = Solver(vars(config))

    if config.mode == 'train':
        solver.train()
    elif config.mode == 'test':
        solver.test()

    return solver
```

Once solver.py is called, the initial few lines of solver look like this- (its a long piece of code as can be seen in the repo, I have only shown the relevant lines of code below)-

```
class Solver(object):
    DEFAULTS = {}

    def __init__(self, config):

        self.__dict__.update(Solver.DEFAULTS, **config)
```

The original script (SMAP.sh from the repo) passing arguments to main.py (again see repo) and with argparser, the config is initiallized, I am trying to avois using a script and argeparser and directly initialize config.

But when i tried creating the dictionary - I get the error **TypeError: vars() argument must have **dict** attribute**

Comment: `self.__dict__` is the dictionary containing the class's attributes. `update()` is a normal dictionary method, it merges the given dictionary into the one that it's called on.

Comment: okay I see, But if I want to initialize config how would I do so? Should I create a class config, and then create an object of it?

Comment: What this does is allow you to provide a dictionary of configurations when you create the object: `Solver({"foo": 1, "bar": 10})`

Comment: How are the arguments obtained from the shell script? In the end, the python code that creates a Solver object has converted whatever the shell script did to a `dict` and used that to create the object. You do the same thing: Use a dict to create the object.

Comment: The arguments like num_epochs, batch_size are given in a script, which runs main.py. main.py uses `config = parser.parse_args()` to create config and calls solver. I am trying to avoid using `config = parser.parse_args()` as I want to directly create config and give the arguments to solver